# Is there an easy way to implement DateTimePicker in Django Crispy forms?

Tags: datetimepicker, django-crispy-forms, django-2.2

I have a DeliveryNote model which contains datetime field.

```
class DeliveryNote(models.Model):
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField("Date Completed")
```

But on ModelForms, there is only DateField available:

```
date_completed = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

As it can be seen that there is not time selection:

[image]

I have looked to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865120/datetimepicker-with-django-crispy-forms), but can not able to implement it. Any idea how to implement datetime field easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTimeInput` widget and `datetime-local` as input type:

```
    date_completed = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today,
        widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}))
```